# ¿Se usa "está" o "están" con "la mayoría de las personas"?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, número-gramatical, concordancia-verbal

¿Se usa *la mayoría de las personas está* o *la mayoría de las personas están* ?
Algunas veces se usan ambas versiones.

Por ejemplo, ¿cómo traduce la siguiente oración a inglés?

*Algunas veces es útil saber "qué tan largos son la mayoría de nombres."*

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Aunque es preferida la concordancia con el verbo en plural, esta se puede establecer tanto en plural, como en singular dependiendo de qué se tome como parte central del sujeto. Si es el cuantificador singular, entonces se hace la concordancia en singular; si, por el contrario, se toma como parte central del sujeto el sustantivo en plural, entonces se hace la concordancia en plural.

Tomemos como ejemplo

> *La mayoría de los asistentes se retiró al caer la noche.*
>
> *La mayoría de los asitentes se retiraron al caer la noche.*

En el primer caso se ha tomado como parte central del sujeto *mayoría* y, por tanto, se realiza la concordancia con el verbo en singular.

En el segundo caso se ha tomado como parte central del sujeto *los asitentes* y, por tanto, se realiza la concordancia con el verbo en plural.

Al respecto, en su [`entrada sobre concordancia`](http://www.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=XEVeLzVZaD6CG25cW5), el Diccionario Panispánico de Dudas menciona:

> 4.8. Sujeto de cuantificador + de + sustantivo en plural. Los sustantivos cuantificadores son aquellos que, siendo singulares,
>   designan una pluralidad de seres de cualquier clase; la clase se
>   especifica mediante un complemento con de cuyo núcleo es, normalmente,
>   un sustantivo en plural: la mitad de los animales, la mayoría de los
>   profesores, una minoría de los presentes, el resto de los libros, el
>   diez por ciento de los votantes, un grupo de alumnos, un montón de
>   cosas, infinidad de amigos, multitud de problemas, etc. La mayor parte
>   de estos cuantificadores admiten la concordancia con el verbo tanto en
>   singular como en plural, dependiendo de si se juzga como núcleo del
>   sujeto el cuantificador singular o el sustantivo en plural que
>   especifica su referencia, siendo mayoritaria, en general, la
>   concordancia en plural: «Hacia 1940 la mayoría de estos poetas había
>   escrito lo mejor de su obra» (Paz Sombras [Méx. 1983]); «La mayoría de
>   los visitantes habían salido» (Marías Corazón [Esp. 1992]); «Una
>   veintena de personas ocupaba la sala» (Chavarría Rojo [Ur. 2002]);
>   «Una veintena de curiosos observaban de lejos a un piquete» (PzReverte
>   Maestro [Esp. 1988]); sin embargo, cuando el verbo lleva un atributo o
>   un complemento predicativo, solo es normal la concordancia en plural:
>   «La mayoría de estos asesinos son muy inteligentes» (Mendoza Satanás
>   [Col. 2002]); «La inmensa mayoría de las casas permanecían vacías»
>   (Savater Caronte [Esp. 1981]). Los sustantivos cuantificadores que se
>   usan sin determinante (infinidad, cantidad, multitud) establecen la
>   concordancia obligatoriamente en plural, pues, en realidad, forman con
>   la preposición de una locución que determina al sustantivo plural, que
>   es el verdadero núcleo del sujeto: «Infinidad de católicos
>   desatendieron semejante orden pontificia» (Vidal Ocultismo [Esp.
>   1995]); «Cantidad de organizaciones se dedican a [...] ayudar a
>   personas que han sido víctimas de abuso sexual» (NHerald [EE. UU.]
>   21.10.97).

**Así pues solo en un caso es obligatoria la concordancia en plural: cuando el verbo lleva un atributo o un complemento predicativo.**

El el caso concreto de tu pregunta al final

> *...algunas veces es útil saber qué tan largos son la mayoría de nombres.*

la longitud en cuestión hace referencia directa a *los nombres* (no al cuantificador *mayoría*), así que debe hacerse la concordancia en plural.

Comment: ¿Cómo traduce la oración debajo de mi pregunta?

Comment: @Dombey este es un sitio de uso del español, así que no sé si una traducción al inglés sea correcta aquí. Hay un sitio para consultas en inglés. Yo no soy hablante nativo de inglés, así que puede no ser lo mejor, pero yo diría "sometimes it is useful to know how long many of the names are".

Comment: @GonzalMedina: _...**most** of the names..._.

Comment: @CarlosEugenioThompsonPinzón Ooops! You're right. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Uso "la mayoría de las personas está". La concordancia es con "la mayoría" y no con "las personas."

I would use está. The agreement is with "la mayoría" and not with "las personas."